# unable to implement CMMotionManager with ios app

Tags: ios, accelerometer, cmmotionmanager

I'm trying to change the UILabel value if we tilt the device, for that i'm trying to implement CMMotionManager but its not working for me, this the code I'm using,

I have add CoreMotion in lib.

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

 CMMotionManager *motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = .2;

    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];

    if ([motionManager isAccelerometerAvailable] == YES)
    {

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

        [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue  withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error)
         {

             CMAcceleration acceleration = data.acceleration;


             if(acceleration.y < -0.25) { // tilting the device to the right

                 [self setTextforlabel:@"right"];

             } else if (acceleration.y > 0.25) { // tilting the device to the left

                                  [self setTextforlabel:@"left"];
             }
         }];
    }
```

whats the problem here, `isAccelerometerAvailable` is always false and

`startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue` it will not fire in.

can any one help me for this or there any other way to do for tilt device.

Comment: I got it, for tilt we need to check with DeviceMotion and its working for me in ios 7 but not in ios6, any comment for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run it on device or in stimulator accelerometer does not work in stimulator

Comment: I have check with Device